# What's the purpose of listening/share other people/own music?

Tags: self, perception, subjectivity, music

For psychology and physics motivations, I'll never get the whole idea about a piece of music made by other peoples (it won't translate from his mind to my mind; even because what I'll listening, even if me and author in are the same room, is affected by biological differences and human experience/perception).

So in fact, every time I listening to others music (or I get art in general), is very probably I'm getting it wrong (from original idea).

The same if I make music and I share it across humans: I bet nobody will get it as I do.

What's the purpose of doing somethings that is/will be "wrong" by "how it is"?

Comment: Why do you think that to listen music is "to express/transfer an idea" ?

Comment: I think Alan Watts had some opinions on this.  I don't think [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHnIJeE3LAI) is quite exactly trying to convey an answer to the topic you bring up, but it seems just related enough to be worth listening to and interpreting wrongly.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: "messages" sounds better? Because if we talk about "sound", well... its always going to change. So I presume what matter is the message, right?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your quandary is? Art and music are not meant to mean the same thing to every individual, so there is no "wrong" as you suggest. Beauty is in the eye of the beholder!